# Como puedo recuperar un datatable que lo tengo en una clase, como un objeto a mi formulario?

Tags: c#

amigos, estoy tratando de trabajar en capas, tengo la capa_negocios donde tengo mis entidades, quiero llamarlas desde mi capa de presentacion, pero no he podido o no se como hacer la llamada desde el form, les presento mi codigo en mi clase a ver si me dan una mano.

```
public static DataTable MpxMostrarEmpresas(string acCadena)
        {
            // Configurando los command de saliad
            SqlConnection aoConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.efamConnectionString);
            SqlCommand aoExecuteStorePCommand = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter aoDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            // Creaando un nuevo DataTable
            DataTable dtFactura = new DataTable("aoDT");

            try
            {
                // Procesando la secuencia de los commandos
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand = aoConnection.CreateCommand();
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DBO.empresas WHERE Empresa = 1";
                // Habrir la cadena de conexion, Executar el SP y cerrar la conexion.
                aoConnection.Open();
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                aoDataAdapter.Fill(dtFactura);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - En Cargar Datos Empresa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            // Retornando el datatable
            return dtFactura;
        }
```

Hasta alli estoy bien, pero desde el formulario necesito pasarle una entidad Empresa para que se llene con datatable dtfactura y una vez llena la entidad recuperar los datos de esta en el form. Quiero trabajar en capas, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me concentraré en la última parte de lo que escribes, Alfredo.

> Quiero trabajar en capas

No estoy completamente seguro si tu entidad debería estar en la capa de negocios. Si tu entidad solamente es una clase simple, diría yo pertenece a la capa de acceso a datos, para que las clases encargadas de traer y llenar el objeto desde base de datos no dependa de ninguna otra capa, especialmente si cada capa es un proyecto distinto y cada capa está en servidores diferentes.

Ahora, a tu pregunta. No sabemos qué tecnología estás utilizando. No sabemos si son páginas aspx, si utilizas MVC, o si es Angular sobre .Net.

Pero, en general, **la capa de presentación debería llamar a la capa de lógica de negocios, la cual, a su vez, debería llamar la capa de acceso a datos.**

La capa de presentación no debería por ningún motivo llamar a la capa de acceso a datos. Eso **viola directamente** la arquitectura n-capas; además que estás haciendo a la capa de presentación dependiente de negocios y de datos, a la vez.

Por lo tanto, tu capa de presentación debería crear una instancia de la clase de lógica de negocios, y tu capa de negocios debería llamar al acceso a datos,.

Tu capa de datos debería retornar una colección de facturas

```
List<Factura>
```

, y la clase de negocios debería hacer que las reglas de negocio se cumplan para ese conjunto de datos y devolver a la capa de presentación el objeto adecuado **(puede ser un ViewModel, un DTO,etc.)**. La capa de presentación tomará ese objeto y lo presentará en un dataset, en un plugin javascript, o cualquier otro método que hayas elegido. Saludos.

**EDIT**

Ya que estás en WinForms, probablemente estés utilizando un DataGridView para mostrar los datos. Tienes dos maneras de mostrar los datos en el grid utilizando la propiedad DataSource del DataGridView.

1-. Con una lista

```
public class FacturaForm()
{ //suponemos que este es el form donde muestras las facturas
   DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
   public void MostrarFacturas()
     {
        var facturas = new List<Factura>();
        var logicaNegocio = new FacturaBusinessLogic();
        facturas = logicaNegocio.FacturasObtener();
        dgv.DataSource = facturas;
      }
}
```

2.- Con un BindingList y BindingSource

```
  public class FacturaForm()
     { //suponemos que este es el form donde muestras las facturas
         DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
         public void MostrarFacturas()
            {
                var facturas = new List<Factura>();
                var logicaNegocio = new FacturaBusinessLogic();
                facturas = logicaNegocio.FacturasObtener();


                var bindingList = new BindingList<Factura>(facturas);
                var bindingSource = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
                dgv.DataSource = source;
            }
      }
```

La diferencia es que **List** no implementa IBindingList, así que el DataGridView no sabrá los cambios que hay en la lista, ni las modificaciones que le hagas dentro del dgv. BindingList sí estará al tanto de dichos cambios.

Comment: Graacias Ariel, estoy con C# con Winforms y a como menciono quiero trabajarlo en capas.

Comment: Ariel, perfecto este codigo que me facilitaste es lo segundo que necesitaria, te me adelantaste a mi pregunta. Trabajo con devexpress, data grid, no debo tener problemas, solo que quiero mejorar la nueva aplicacion o trabajar a como mencione en capas, la anterior la tenia con dataset. Salludos

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que necesitas una función que al enviarle un objeto Empresa, le devuelva este objeto lleno con los datos de la consulta a la base.

Primero deberías eliminar el string acCadena porque no lo estas utilizando, en su caso deberías recibir por parámetro un objeto de la entidad Empresa y devolver este objeto lleno con los datos que obtuviste en tu consulta.

```
public static Empresa MpxMostrarEmpresas(Empresa emp)
        {
            // Configurando los command de saliad
            SqlConnection aoConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.efamConnectionString);
            SqlCommand aoExecuteStorePCommand = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter aoDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            // Creaando un nuevo DataTable
            DataTable dtFactura = new DataTable("aoDT");

            try
            {
                // Procesando la secuencia de los commandos
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand = aoConnection.CreateCommand();
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DBO.empresas WHERE Empresa = " + emp.Empresa;
                // Habrir la cadena de conexion, Executar el SP y cerrar la conexion.
                aoConnection.Open();
                aoDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                aoDataAdapter.Fill(dtFactura);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - En Cargar Datos Empresa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            // Retornando el datatable
            //return dtFactura;

            //aca cargas los datos del datatable en tu objeto emp, por ejemplo:
            emp.nombre = dtFactura.Rows[0]["nombre"];

            return emp;            
        }
```

Entonces desde tu form declaras el objeto empresa y lo cargas de esta manera:

```
Empresa obj = new Empresa();
obj = MpxMostrarEmpresas(obj);
```

Con eso ya estaría cargada tu entidad.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Nicolas, si te entiendo es lo que quiero o trato de hacer, llenar la entidad la probare en este momento tu solucion y la otra aclaracion que me hace Nicolas. Las dos las veo validad una para traerme los datos y la otra para trabajar en capas.

Comment: Listo nicolas, eso es lo que necesitaba, ya lo tengo, seguire trabajando en lo que estoy tratando de implementar. Saludos